# How to add ng-mocks to a fresh Angular 15 project

Tags: angular, ng-mocks

I recently created a new Angular project using the latest Angular 15 CLI. Now I want to add ng-mocks to it.

I can install the dependency, but there is no longer a `test.ts` file where I can add the configuration for ng-mocks. When I add the file myself, my tests are no longer found.

What is the proper way to add ng-mocks to an Angular 15 project without `test.ts`?

Comment: Are there other files: either `src/setup-jest.ts` or  `src/test-setup.ts`

Comment: There are no other test files. Angular CLI 15 does not generate them anymore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

now `test.ts` is generated by angular (`node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/builders/karma/index.js`), if you want to customize it, you need to do the next:

create `src/test.ts` and put there:

```js
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting,
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

// Initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting(), {
  errorOnUnknownElements: true,
  errorOnUnknownProperties: true
});
```

Then add it to `angular.json`:

```json
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts", // <- here
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
```

and add it to `tsconfig.spec.ts`:

```json
  "include": [
    "src/test.ts", // <- here
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
```

profit, now you can extend `test.ts` again.

Comment: Ah I had a similar issue when upgrading a project from Angular v14 => v15 (as opposed to a fresh v15 project), but this helped me get that sorted out. Thank you!